# recursive query to get all children

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I have an `edibles` table with the following definition:

```
 Column |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer               |           | not null |
 name   | character varying(60) |           | not null |
 parent | integer               |           | not null |
```

It has data such as:

```
 id |         name         | parent
----+----------------------+--------
  1 | fruit                |      0
  2 | veg                  |      0
  3 | cruciferous          |      2
  4 | horseradish          |      3
  5 | colanaceae           |      1
  6 | tomatoes             |      5
  7 | aubergine            |      5
  8 | chinese eggplant     |      7
  9 | costoluto fiorentino |      6
 10 | calvaceae            |      0
```

The table is self-referencing to cater for the parent-child relationship of the edibles.

I am trying to write a query where I get all children, no matter how nested for a given `id`.

**Desired output**

`where id = 1` should return

```
 id |         name         | parent
----+----------------------+--------
  1 | fruit                |      0
  5 | colanaceae           |      1
  6 | tomatoes             |      5
  7 | aubergine            |      5
  8 | chinese eggplant     |      7
  9 | costoluto fiorentino |      6
```

`where id = 10` should return

```
 id |         name         | parent
----+----------------------+--------
 10 | calvaceae            |      0
```

and finally `where id = 6` should return:

```
 id |         name         | parent
----+----------------------+--------
  6 | tomatoes             |      5
  9 | costoluto fiorentino |      6
```

I haven't done any recursive SQL before, and I'm not really sure where to start.

I have created a [db-fiddle too](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fi1j727QhhFu3UaFKfU5is/4).

**Update**

Sorry, forgot to mention, the Postgres version is 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

```
-- create the table
create table edibles (
  id integer not null,
  name varchar(60) not null,
  parent integer not null);
  
-- insert data
insert into edibles (id, name, parent) values
  (1, 'fruit', 0),
  (2, 'veg', 0),
  (3, 'cruciferous', 2),
  (4, 'horseradish', 3),
  (5, 'colanaceae', 1),
  (6, 'tomatoes', 5),
  (7, 'aubergine', 5),
  (8, 'chinese eggplant', 7),
  (9, 'costoluto fiorentino', 6),
  (10, 'calvaceae', 0);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
with RECURSIVE cte as 
(
  select * from edibles where id=1
  union all
  select e.* from edibles e inner join cte on e.parent=cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | fruit | 0 |
| 5 | colanaceae | 1 |
| 6 | tomatoes | 5 |
| 7 | aubergine | 5 |
| 8 | chinese eggplant | 7 |
| 9 | costoluto fiorentino | 6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fi1j727QhhFu3UaFKfU5is/1)

For ID=6

**Schema (PostgreSQL v12)**

**Query #2**

```
with RECURSIVE cte as 
(
  select * from edibles where id=6
  union all
  select e.* from edibles e inner join cte on e.parent=cte.id
)
select * from cte;
```

| id | name | parent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | tomatoes | 5 |
| 9 | costoluto fiorentino | 6 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fi1j727QhhFu3UaFKfU5is/1)

Comment: Sorry, Kazi, I forgot to mention that the Postgres version is 10.

Comment: Don't worry. It will work the same way in that version. Best wishes.

Answer (score 3):

The recursive CTE is actually pretty simple:

```
with recursive cte as (
      select 6 as id
-------------^ just change this value
      union all
      select e.id
      from cte join
           edibles e
           on e.parent = cte.id
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4ac0421f716c1a4c779496c2eb485cf4) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Sorry, Gordon, I forgot to mention that the Postgres version is 10. The above doesn't seem to work in 10.

Comment: @J86 . . . Of course it does:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4ac0421f716c1a4c779496c2eb485cf4.